# Should PATH contain directories or full paths to binaries?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, path, sh

I am trying to set up a correct `PATH`, but I'm wondering what it should contain. If I have

```
/usr/bin/ls
/usr/local/bin/ls
```

and I want to prefer the one in `/usr/local/bin`, which of the following should I use?

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin/ls:/usr/bin/ls
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

or something else entirely?

> This is not *per se* a suitable question for Stack Overflow.
>   I expect this to be closed as General Computing or Too Broad;
>   but the *answer* is frequently needed by beginners, so I hope this won't be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `PATH` works only with directories, not with single files

From the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) (emphasis mine)

> PATH
>      This variable shall represent the sequence of path prefixes that certain functions and utilities apply in searching for an executable file known only by a filename. The prefixes shall be separated by a colon ( ':' ). [...] The list shall be searched from beginning to end, **applying the filename to each prefix**, until an executable file with the specified name and appropriate execution permissions is found.

When you type in `ls` into your shell and your `PATH` is set to `/usr/local/bin/ls:/usr/bin/ls` then your shell will …

1. … look for an executable with the path `/usr/local/bin/ls/ls` (note the double `ls` at the end).
2. As that path does not exist on your system your shell will proceed to look for an executable with the path `/usr/bin/ls/ls` (double `ls` again). That path also doesn't exist.
3. The shell couldn't find an executable using all paths in `PATH` so your shell will print something like `bash: ls: command not found`.

So, what did we learn? Paths listed by `PATH` *have* to be directories. You cannot list single files. Therefore the correct answer in your case is `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`.

---

#### Where things get interesting

Imagine the following situation. You have two versions of program `c1` and two versions of program `c2`. The different versions are stored in the directories `/a/` and `/b/`.

```
/a/c1
/a/c2
/b/c1
/b/c2
```

How can we set `PATH` to prefer `/a/c1` over `/b/c1/` but at the same time `/b/c2` over `/a/c2`?

Sadly, there is no way to achieve this directly as we can only specify directories in `PATH`.  We have to move/rename some files or create symlinks and use the symlinks inside the paths. One possible solution:

```
mkdir /c
ln -s /a/c1 /c/c1
ln -s /b/c2 /c/c2
export PATH=/c:/a:/b
```

The trailing `:/a:/b` is not really necessary here. I included them under the assumption that `/a` and `/b` contain more executables than just `c1` and `c2`.

Comment: Nice corollary, but that part would properly belong in the nominated duplicate IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, as you can easily find out through experimentation, the variable `PATH` should already contain a list of **directories** which are consulted in that order.  In fact, you should already find that you have `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` in the default `PATH`, usually in this order (though perhaps with other directories between them, and certainly with more directories around them).

To inspect your current `PATH` value, try

```
echo "$PATH"
```

or for a slightly more human-readable rendering

```
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"     # bash only
```

or

```
echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\012'  # any POSIX system
```

If you managed to set your `PATH` to an invalid value (which would cause simple commands like `ls` and `cat` to no longer be found, and produce `command not found` errors) you can try

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr
```

to hopefully at least restore the essential functionality so that you can use `cp` or a simple system editor to get back to the original, safe, system default `PATH`.

Comment: POSIX way to display `$PATH`: `IFS=:; for dir in $PATH; do echo "$dir"; done`

Comment: That  wrecks your `IFS` though. You can wrap the whole thing in parentheses to work around that.

Comment: `unset IFS` when done. This is how you use IFS anyway.

Comment: Well that works if you are sure it wasn't set to something else before. But you can't know that in the general case.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Do not make any assumptions about the content of `IFS`. If you use it, set it or reset it.