# Exporting $PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin does not restore commands

Tags: bash

I added a new python script to my .bash_profile, but the command would not work after sourcing my .bash_profile. I, therefore, tried another command in the .bash_profile to see if the issue was specific to the new command. I realised that none of the commands added to the .bash_profile using "export PATH=$PATH:[path to command] worked. I tried to export, thinking that my .bash_profile was not being exported and the commands were not being found, but now I cannot use basic commands on bash, such as `cat` or `ls` and I am not sure what I have done wrong or how to fix.

Here is a step-by-step of my commands and outputs. I would show you the .bash_profile, but I cannot `cat`...

Testing command after adding to .bash_profile:

```
u1983390@vettel:~$ SendEmail.py test test
SendEmail.py: command not found
```

Ensuring the command works when the full path is provided, which it does:

```
u1983390@vettel:~$ /home/u1983390/Scripts/SendEmail.py test test 
Sending job status email...
```

Testing other commands in .bash_profile PATH to see if they work:

```
u1983390@vettel:~$ AED_cdf_generator.pl
AED_cdf_generator.pl: command not found
```

I then tried to export the PATH in the hope that the commands would work:

```
u1983390@vettel:~$ export $PATH
```

I got the following error message:

```
-bash: export: `/home/u1983390/Scripts/SendEmail.py:/shared/software/miniconda3/envs/maker_0520/bin:/home/u1983390/apps/Genome_Annotation/bin/AED_cdf_generator.pl': not a valid identifier
```

Now no basic commands will work:

```
u1983390@vettel:~$ cat .bash_profile 
Command 'cat' is available in '/bin/cat'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
cat: command not found
```

I am not sure what I have done that has caused the issue. I have found similar instances [online](https://superuser.com/questions/595818/add-usr-local-sbin-to-the-path-of-a-user), and consequently tried `export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"`, which appears to have been added to my path, but still, the basic commands do not work. I have tried to add a couple of variations, but still no luck.

PATH currently:

```
/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/home/u1983390/Scripts/SendEmail.py:/shared/software/miniconda3/envs/maker_0520/bin:/home/u1983390/apps/Genome_Annotation/bin/AED_cdf_generator.pl:/usr/local/sbin
```

I have tried adding `usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr` to the PATH but still no success.

```
u1983390@vettel:~$ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr
u1983390@vettel:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr
u1983390@vettel:~$ ls
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

I recognise the issue is due to the files in the PATH, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285676/should-path-contain-directories-or-full-paths-to-binaries), but I have no commands available to fix it. How do I restore basic commands?

Comment: The standard `PATH` should contain more than just `/usr/bin` but the proper fix is to back out whatever changes you made to your startup file.

Comment: For what it's worth, the correct syntax would be `export PATH` without a dollar sign; but `PATH` should already be exported anyway, so you really don't need that here.

Comment: I closed and logged back in, exporting PATH 'usr/bin'  without $, but I still experience the issue:

Last login: Mon Feb 27 15:39:58 2023 from 51.146.199.236
`echo $PATH
/home/u1983390/Scripts/SendEmail.py:/shared/software/miniconda3/envs/maker_0520/bin:/home/u1983390/apps/Genome_Annotation/bin/AED_cdf_generator.pl
u1983390@vettel:~$ PATH=/usr/bin
u1983390@vettel:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin
u1983390@vettel:~$ cat .bash_profile 
Command 'cat' is available in '/bin/cat'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
cat: command not found`

Comment: Like the error message tells you, you need `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` to get access to e.g. `cat`. Other directories to probably include in your `PATH` are `/usr/local/bin` and perhaps `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin`. What exactly makes sense also depends on your precise OS and version. But again, the proper fix is to return your `.bash_profile` to what it was before you started experimenting. On some systems, you can find the default version in `/etc/skel/bash_profile`

Comment: I added a second duplicate which should help with troubleshooting. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a site for _programming_ questions, though, not general computer troubleshooting and support.

Comment: (on some modern Linux-y operating systems `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are the same directory, but what constitutes an appropriate PATH really depends on the specific OS/distro/&c in use)