# Mac Ventura 13.5.2 RuntimeError: espeak not installed on your system

Tags: python, installation, runtime-error, espeak

I'm using a Mac version 13.5.2, trying to run espeak on a conda env (python 3.9, separate environment from base). I previously installed it using homebrew.

I have tried to follow all instructions including looking at previous troubleshooting tips from StackOverflow. Yet I continue to run into this RuntimeError. The issue comes from backend.py not recognizing that I've installed espeak (can't find the dylib maybe)? I did check to see if there was a legit dylib file through python if statements and it said there was (PosixPath('/opt/homebrew/Cellar/espeak/1.48.04_1/lib/libespeak.1.1.48.dylib')), but the backend isn't working.

I've tried adding the path in other different ways:

Running
`sudo nano /etc/paths`
Then adding the path with dylib:
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/espeak/1.48.04_1/lib/libespeak.1.1.48.dylib`

I've also exported the var PHONEMIZER_ESPEAK_LIBRARY and set it to the dylib path stated above

I've also tried adding this path
`/opt/homebrew/bin/espeak`
Plus the conda path that leads to the directory containing espeak `anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/phonemizer`

I even tried installing python-espeak (pip install python-espeak) but it failed to build. Giving me this message:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-espeak
  Running setup.py clean for python-espeak
Failed to build python-espeak
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-espeak, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Is it my console that's the issue? Please advise.

I'm using a Mac version 13.5.2, trying to run espeak on a conda env (python 3.9, separate environment from base). I previously installed it using homebrew.

I have tried to follow all instructions including looking at previous troubleshooting tips from StackOverflow. Yet I continue to run into this RuntimeError. The issue comes from backend.py not recognizing that I've installed espeak (can't find the dylib maybe)? I did check to see if there was a legit dylib file through python if statements and it said there was (PosixPath('/opt/homebrew/Cellar/espeak/1.48.04_1/lib/libespeak.1.1.48.dylib')), but the backend isn't working.

I've tried adding the path in other different ways:

Running
`sudo nano /etc/paths`
Then adding the path with dylib:
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/espeak/1.48.04_1/lib/libespeak.1.1.48.dylib`

I've also exported the var PHONEMIZER_ESPEAK_LIBRARY and set it to the dylib path stated above

I've also tried adding this path
`/opt/homebrew/bin/espeak`
Plus the conda path that leads to the directory containing espeak `anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/phonemizer`

I even tried installing python-espeak (pip install python-espeak) but it failed to build. Giving me this message:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-espeak
  Running setup.py clean for python-espeak
Failed to build python-espeak
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-espeak, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

UPDATE

Tried testing again and getting this error. dylib file can't be found...
E   RuntimeError: failed to load espeak library: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/espeak/1.48.04_1/lib/libespeak.1.1.48.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/espeak/1.48.04_1/lib/libespeak.1.1.48.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/espeak/1.48.04_1/lib/libespeak.1.1.48.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/espeak/1.48.04_1/lib/libespeak.1.1.48.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

Comment: The espeak library you have is built for Apple Silicon (arm64) but your Python is x86_64 (i.e. being run via Rosetta translation). You'll need to fix that first, so you're actually running arm64 Python.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285676/should-path-contain-directories-or-full-paths-to-binaries